# Sharepoint - Folder link does not resolve

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, directory, designer

Has anyone encountered the issue when you copy your folder link "short link" via Get link but when you go to the copied link you're routed to root folder of the library?
e.g.

short link  `https://ts.company.com/sites/YourSiteName/Shared%20Documents/General%20Documentation/Tst_genDoc_sub`

The short link above resolves to the one below

```
https://ts.company.com/sites/YourSiteName/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/YourSiteName/Shared%20Documents/General%20Documentation/Tst_genDoc_sub&FolderCTID=0x012000000000000000000000000000000&RootFolder=/sites/YourSiteName/Shared%20Documents/General%20Documentation/Tst_genDoc_sub&FolderCTID=0x012000000000000000000000000000000
```

I've observed that if I take out the part after the second "`&FolderCTID`" it creates a working link like the one below this goes to the correct part of my shared doc.

`https://ts.company.com/sites/YourSiteName/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/YourSiteName/Shared%20Documents/General%20Documentation/Tst_genDoc_sub&FolderCTID=0x012000000000000000000000000000000`

But my problem would be that Sharepoint automatically resolves to the wrong link whenever I use the short link. Is there a way around this?

I've already tried to check the settings but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Edited wrong folder

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by doing a Site definition Reset for the Allitems.aspx of the specific Documentation Library.